# If species are reproductively isolated, then how are interspecific hybridisations carried out?

Tags: zoology, species, sexual-reproduction, protein-interaction, animal-husbandry

during fertilisation there is compatibility test done so that both sperms and eggs are of same species. the zona pellucida of egg bears sperm specific receptor proteins(ZP3 receptor proteins) which bind with species specific proteins (bindin) present on sperm. so during interspecific hybridisaton( for example mule which is hybrid of donkey and horse) how fertilisation between gametes of different species carried out? what is exactly the mechanism behind this?

Comment: Mules existed for quite a long time - maybe 5000 years? - before any of the relevant biology was known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule  Apparently there is enough similarity in sex pheromones &c that male donkeys are quite willing to mate with female horses.  But that's not saying much, since a couple of my female acquaintances who have donkeys have told me that they just don't ever bend over when they're in the same corral as a male.

Comment: Hello and welcome at Biology SE! Please take our [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how to ask good questions. Can you please clarify your question? Are you interested in the specific molecular mechanisms behind egg and sperm cell interactions or you would like to know how is it possible that different species can mate?

Comment: i want to know about specific molecular mechanism behind egg and sperm cell interaction during interspecific hybridisation processes.

Comment: Why do you think that molecular mechanism would be different compared to intraspecific matings?

Comment: i am not able to understand that how gametes of different species involved in fertilisation. what about species specificity? how is it compatible?